# Change size of label annotations in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I am trying to change text label sizes inside my plot (not the axes, rather the label annotations)

I am working with a phyloseq object but I don't think that matters.
Here is the code and the output. Any suggestions?

```
plot_ordination(prokaryote_ra, ordBC, color = "Stage", label="SampleID") +  ggtitle("PCoA: Bray-Curtis")
```

graph of ordination plot with label annotations that are too small

[image]

Comment: Dear Zack Thanknyou very much for your answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like size for the text label is a fixed value 2, in the *plot_ordination()* function see [L1135 at GitHub](https://github.com/joey711/phyloseq/blob/5c532790722d839ed2a6e991d67fa6c96f8c9745/R/plot-methods.R#L1135) in *plot-methods.R* file

```
...
p = p + geom_text(label_map, data=rm.na.phyloseq(DF, label),
                      size=2, vjust=1.5, na.rm=TRUE) # <--- here size is set to 2
...
```

Solution would be either submit an issue at GitHub, and wait for an update from maintainer, or copy paste the function locally, and change the *size* to match your needs.